# Extanding the User model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, backend, one-to-one

I am trying to build my first Django backend project, so i'm trying to creatre a REST API end-point that gets a user registration data in json file from the front-end and save it on the database if it's valid.
I am trying to save the additional user information in a new model called Player and link it to the default User model using one-to-one-field.

When i recive the json file with the data from the front-end the a new user with the data is created in the User model, also a new row is created in the Player model that connected to the user we just created in the User model. But the problem is the fields "height" and "handicap" remain empty.

I don't know how to save the "height" and "handicap" parameters into the new Player instance.

This is my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from datetime import *

# This model extend the basic built-in User model, by adding additional information on the uesr like
# handicap score anf height.
class Player(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # connecting this model to the User model
    # (cascade means when deleting a user row in the user table
    # the match row in this table will automatically will be deleted)
    handicap = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(28)])
    height = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(250)])
    registration_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())

    #a listener that listen to the User model, if a new user as been save, it creates a new row in the player model with the new user in the user field
    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:  # if a new user created in the User model
            Player.objects.create(user=instance)  # creating a new row in player, inserting the new user instance to the user field

    # if a User is saved we update the user instance to the player user field
    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
```

This is my serializers.py file:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from .models import Player

# class serializer that handel the data from user registration
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True, validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])  # making sure that the email that the user entered have not being used by another user
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True, validators=[validate_password])  # checking that the password is valid
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    height = serializers.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(250)])
    handicap = serializers.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(28)])

    class Meta:  # nested class that gives the serializer details
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'password2', 'height', 'handicap')

    # overriding the built-in validation method of the model serializer
    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs['password'] != attrs['password2']:  # if the 2 passwords on the form don't match
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': "passwords don't match!"})  # raising an error
        return attrs

    # overriding the built-in create method
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # creating a user instance with the data came from the registration
        user = User.objects.create(username=validated_data['email'], first_name=validated_data['first_name'], last_name=validated_data['last_name'], email=validated_data['email'], password=validated_data['password'])
        user.save()  # saving the user registration data to the database
        player = Player.objects.get(user=user)
        player.height = validated_data['height']
        player.handicap = validated_data['handicap']
        player.save()
        return user
```

This is my views.py file:

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import *

# Create your views here.
class RegistrationView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
```

This is my urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import RegistrationView

urlpatterns = [
    path('registration/', RegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration')
]
```

**Does someone know what to do in order to also save the "height" and "handicap" to the Player model?**

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing can be solved with a [serializer relation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#serializer-relations), more specifically with a [nested relationship](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).

I have tried to preserve your code as much as I could. Although, some changes are necessary or just have been made to make the code cleaner.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class Player(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    handicap = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(28)])
    height = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(250)])

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Player.objects.create(user=instance)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Removed 'registration_date' field. The Abstract user model already has a field called 'date_joined', no need to store the same information. Also, the second function 'save_user_profile ' was not necessary.

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from core.models import Player

class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    height = serializers.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(250)])
    handicap = serializers.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(28)])

    class Meta:
        model = Player
        exclude = ['user']

class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True, validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True, validators=[validate_password])
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    player = PlayerSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'password2', 'player')

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs['password'] != attrs['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': "passwords don't match!"})
        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        pw2 = validated_data.pop('password2')
        player = validated_data.pop('player')

        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        user.player.height = player['height']
        user.player.handicap = player['handicap']
        user.player.save()
        
        return user
```

Created a PlayerSerializer to nest within the RegistrationSerializer. To represent the fields of 'handicap' and 'height' by excluding the 'user' field.

On the create method, poping keys out of the dictionary to use the **kwargs for a cleaner format. Later, using the keys to update relationship values.

views.py and urls.py remains untouched.

Comment: Your code only works if in the serializers.py file i add "user.player.save()" before returning the user. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You created the user object in the serializer. In the next line you try to get the user instance from Player model. Actually that user's instance is not created in the Player model yet. So first you have to create that user instance in the Player model.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    # first, get the data for player model from validated data
    height = validated_data.pop.get('height')
    handicap = validated_data.pop.get('handicap')

    # now create the user 
    user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
    
    # now using the user instance, create the player object for that user.
    Player.objects.create(user=user, height=height, handicap=handicap)
    
    return user
```